# retrieving column name from index (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, header

I am looping into a large dataframe with several columns to find some elements, while keeping track of the row and column position with counters.

When I find the element, I would like to find the column header corresponding to that based on the counters. Is there a simple way to do that?

For example, given:

*data = [{'a': 200, 'b': 150, 'c': 200, 'd': 140, 'e':100}]

df6 = pd.DataFrame(data)*

and counter=1, how do I get the corresponding column header 'b' ?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index selection from the column index of a dataframe.

```
data = [{'a': 200, 'b': 150, 'c': 200, 'd': 140, 'e':100}]
df6 = pd.DataFrame(data)
counter = 1
df6.columns[counter]
```

Output:

```
'b'
```

Comment: @Michele if this solution helped you would you [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top).  I'd really appreciate it.